# c# ics file generation for outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, ashx

I have created an ashx file that generates an ics file to use in outlook.  My code for 1 calendar worked fine.  I have now added the fact that the ashx page accepts a guid that goes to check in the database which calendar it should generate.

So people are able to add multiple calendars from a single ashx file, by adding another guid at the end of it.  The problem now is that the first calendar generates fine, but the second one fails.  I see it hit my breakpoint in the ashx file, and it generates everything fine, but outlook doesn't seem to receive it.  I assumed outlook blocked the generation of the ics file because for him it's twice the same link.

I have then implemented url redirect on my webserver to make it seem like multiple different url's to outlook.  Again i see it hit the breakpoints twice, but only 1 calendar is generated and the other one gives me the error "cannot verify or add the calendar to outlook, ..."  And the link IS valid.

is outlook still blocking the refresh of multiple calendars because it comes from the same ashx file?

```
public class CalendarService : IHttpHandler
    {
        private readonly OutlookCalendarDomainLogic _domainLogic = InitializeDomainLogic();

        private static OutlookCalendarDomainLogic InitializeDomainLogic()
        {
            var repository = new OutlookCalendarRepository();
            OutlookCalendarDomainLogic logic = new OutlookCalendarDomainLogic(repository);
            return logic;
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!Guid.TryParse(context.Request["Guid"], out Guid guid))
            {
                return;
            }

            var co = _domainLogic.GetOutlookCalendarByGuid(guid);

         ..... Event generation code
//send the calendar item to the browser
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", CalendarItem.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + CalendarName + ".ics\"");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(CalendarItem);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

any ideas?